# JavaScript: Execute each script sequentially waiting for previous script to finish

Tags: javascript, html, sequence, loading

I have 3 scripts that need to execute in order where each next script waits for the previous script to finish executing. Is there a faster more elegant way to write this?

Say for example I had a production html page that needed to load 20 scripts in order.

note: adding defer to each script does not execute the scripts sequentially.

Here is a working example:

index.html

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>Load scripts in order</title>
    <script>
        const scripts = ["script1.js", "script2.js", "script3.js"]
        for (let i = 1; i < scripts.length; i++) {
            document.head.addEventListener(scripts[i - 1], () => {
                console.log(`finished processing ${scripts[i - 1]}`)
                const nextScript = document.createElement("script")
                nextScript.src = scripts[i]
                document.head.appendChild(nextScript)
            })
        }
    </script>

    <!--load our first script to start sequential loading-->
    <script src="script1.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

script1.js

```js
const foobar = async () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve()
        }, 3000)
        setTimeout(() => {
            reject(new Error("did not finish in time."))
        }, 10000);
    })
}

foobar().then(() => {
    console.log("finished loading script1.js")
    document.head.dispatchEvent(new Event("script1.js"))
} )
```

script2.js

```js
const foobar2 = async () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve()
        }, 3000)
        setTimeout(() => {
            reject(new Error("did not finish in time."))
        }, 10000);
    })
}

foobar2().then(() => {
    console.log("finished loading script2.js")
    document.head.dispatchEvent(new Event("script2.js"))
} )
```

script3.js

```js
console.log("hello world")
```

stack trace:

```
finished loading script1.js
finished processing script1.js
finished loading script2.js
finished processing script2.js
hello world
```

Comment: Where did you get this part? `document.head.addEventListener(scripts[i]...` event listeners need an event like "load", but here you're setting the script name, head doesn't have a load event etc.

Comment: new dispatch events are created in each individual file after everything is done executing, i.e in script1.js: at the end: document.head.dispatchEvent(new Event("script1.js"))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need to use for loop that support async and await `for (const script of scripts)` sample is below

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Load scripts in order</title>
    <script>
        async function loadScript(src) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const script = document.createElement("script");
                script.src = src;
                script.onload = resolve;
                script.onerror = reject;
                document.head.appendChild(script);
            });
        }

        async function loadScriptsSequentially(scripts) {
            for (const script of scripts) {
                console.log(`Loading script: ${script}`);
                await loadScript(script);
                console.log(`Finished loading script: ${script}`);
            }
        }

        const scripts = ["script1.js", "script2.js", "script3.js"];
        loadScriptsSequentially(scripts);
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: 1 problem with this approach is that if a variable is defined in script1.js and called in script2.js, script2.js needs to wait for script1.js variable to become defined manually.

Comment: I dont understand the problem can you please rephrase with example because I thought you wanted to run the script one after the other. This your comment sounds like you want to run all simultaneously